# iOS hybrid app - Backbone framework - performance slow over the time

Tags: ios, backbone.js, marionette, cordova-3, hybrid-mobile-app

We developed iOS hybrid app using Phonegap plugin and Backbone framework with Marionette JS plugin. Our clients will use this for employees to sign-in/sign-out and this app will always open and running 24X7.

App works fine on fresh install for 1 week and app performance starts degrading after 1 week like below

1. Screen rendering very slow
2. Keyboard response is slow
3. If we continuously use it for 1 month, app hangs... we have kill it OR
   restart iPad, then it works fine.

We thought webview is holding cache if app continuously running, we have implementented clearing  webview cache by using phonegap plugin, still no luck.

Will there be any issues if we continuously run the app 24X7 ?

Is backbone framework creating any issues like cache all models data over the time ??

Its really useful if anybody can  help on this.

Comment: Have you tested the site against memory leaks? It's quite easy to create zombie views within Backbone so I wouldn't be surprised if this has something to do with it.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention,  I have used Marionette JS backbone plugin. I assume Marionette js will take care of Zombie views.

Comment: while Marionette provides handy cleanup functions to help avoid zombie views, there's still the possibility you're leaking memory. Check out [this](http://addyosmani.com/blog/taming-the-unicorn-easing-javascript-memory-profiling-in-devtools/) article that details using Chrome DevTools to spot potential memory leaks. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you, will test for memory leak and update you